# How to watch a DVD video with external subtitles in Linux?

Tags: dvd, multimedia, video-subtitles

There are [video players in Windows that can use external subtitles when playing a DVD movie](https://superuser.com/a/719335/162573), but are there in Linux too?

(MPC-HC and PotPlayer are the most obvious solutions for this in Windows. I was not able to instal them in Linux under Wine/Playonlinux.)

**VLC** does seem to work, but with some limitations. At least sometimes what happens is this: it loads the subtitle but from time to time during playback when they should appear they do so for too short a time or not at all; after seeking back or forth they disappear completely and adding them again doesn't work then, I have to restart the movie. So, the idea is to **avoid seeking**. Changing video output doesn't change this.

**Kaffeine** can play the DVD movie very well, but there is no obvious way to add an external subtitle to it. The same for **Xine**, **KMPlayer**, **Dragon**, **Parole**..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MPV** has no menus for DVD, but it works very well. To start the DVD, access the DVD folders and drag&drop the `VIDEO_TS` folder onto the MPV's window. Then do the same with the subtitle file.

[image]

From my experience, in this case the main movie is started directly.

To do that with a command, use something like

`mpv dvd://`

or

`mpv /media/username/*/VIDEO_TS`

To get the correct path for that, mount the DVD, copy/paste the VIDEO_TS path and replace the variable DVD movie name with `*`, as indicated under [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264110/32012) question.

That command can be used in a panel launcher, `.desktop` file or shortcut to start playing the DVD with one click.

An example of  `.desktop` launcher:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=Help;Bindings;Scripts;About
Categories=AudioVideo;Audio;Video;Player;TV;
Exec=mpv /media/username/*/VIDEO_TS
Icon=/home/cip/MY/ico/mpv_dvd.png
MimeType=video/x-theora+ogg;video/x-theora+ogg;video/x-ogm+ogg;video/x-msvideo;video/x-msvideo;video/x-msvideo;video/x-ms-wmv;video/x-ms-asf;video/x-matroska;video/x-flv;video/x-flv;video/x-flic;video/webm;video/vnd.rn-realvideo;video/quicktime;video/ogg;video/mpeg;video/mpeg;video/mpeg;video/mp4;video/mp2t;audio/x-wavpack;audio/x-wav;audio/x-wav;audio/x-vorbis+ogg;audio/x-tta;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-musepack;audio/x-ms-wma;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-mpegurl;audio/x-ape;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/vnd.rn-realaudio;audio/mpeg;audio/mpeg;audio/mpeg;audio/mpeg;audio/mp4;audio/mp4;audio/mp2;audio/mp2;audio/flac;audio/flac;audio/AMR;audio/ac3;audio/aac;application/vnd.rn-realmedia;application/smil;application/sdp;application/ogg;application/ogg;
Name[en_US]=Play DVD in mpv Media Player
Name=Play DVD in mpv Media Player
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Replace `username` with yours and the icon path. You can use this icon :)

[image]

or this

[image]

When the player is started with the command `mpv /dev/sr0`, it will play and seek through all included streams including menus as if in a single file (no [DVD menu support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239762/32012)).

---

**SMPlayer**

[image]

Does the job of adding external subtitles to DVDs. No DVD menus by default, although this can be enabled as an experimental feature under *Options -Preferences - Drives*. (DVD menus seem to work if `mplayer` is selected as multimedia engine but not with the more recent `mpv`.) When the menus are not enabled the main movie is shown in playlist as one separate entry and is easy to identify and add a subtitle to it.

So, start playing the item that corresponds to the movie and then add the external subtitle: it should work very well.

[image]

---

External dvd subtitles usually look better than the ones on the dvd.

Answer (score 0):

Typically I use VLC for watching movies with external subtitle files. Occasionally the timings in the file are a little off, but it has always been an issue with the files, not VLC for me.

What to you mean with "loses it after a while"? The subtitles stop displaying, or they move out of sync with the video?

Comment: I have updated my question on VLC.

Comment: Every time I try it, external subtitle display for a DVD in VLC is erratic. MPV works great though, with a launcher containing the line `Exec=mpv /media/username/*/VIDEO_TS`