# Is it possible to play the VIDEO_TS DVD folder with a generic command (mpv)?

Tags: path, video, dvd, multimedia, mpv

I want to use a command for `mpv` video player that would play the VIDEO_TS folder (which in the case of MPV means starting directly the main video of  the DVD. The main advantage of this is that in this way [MPV can play a DVD movie with external subtitles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259729/32012).)

Normally this can be achieved by drag&drop VIDEO_TS folder onto the player window, which is similar to `mpv file:///media/username/NAME-OF-DVD/VIDEO_TS`.

MPV is not good at using DVD menus and multiple streams: `mpv /dev/sr0` plays all DVD contents including menus one after the other as one stream and that beats my purpose.

On the other hand, as the name of the dvd varies, `mpv file:///media/username/NAME-OF-DVD/VIDEO_TS` cannot be used as a generic command to start DVD the way I want (namely the VIDEO_TS folder of the DVD).

Is there a such generic path to the VIDEO_TS folder that can be used to have a generic command to play that folder?

There is also the more generic question if it is [possible to specify a path in which one of the directory names is variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264110/32012).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [MelBurslan](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/27383/melburslan) answered in a comment under [this more general question (Is it possible to specify a path in which one of the directory levels is variable?)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264107/32012):

> as long as the varying directory level is a single directory, what I
> mean by that, if you have /dir1/dirX/dir3/dir4 and the dirX part is
> not changing like dirX/dirY/dirZ but can only be one of the dirX, dirY
> or dirZ, then you can reference /dir1/dirX/dir3/dir4 as
> /dir1/*/dir3/dir4

So, in the case above, the command that works is simply something like `mpv /media/username/*/VIDEO_TS`

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
mpv dvd:// --dvd-device=/media/username/NAME-OF-DVD/
```

Comment: the idea is to use  a generic name for "NAME-OF-DVD", so that the command be generic. So, in this case it should be `mpv dvd:// --dvd-device=/media/username/*/`

Comment: But that does not work either. What works is `mpv /media/username/*/VIDEO_TS` as indicated in my answer. `mpv dvd:// --dvd-device=/media/username/*/VIDEO_TS` also doesn't work.