# Is it possible to specify a path in which a directory name is variable?

Tags: path, command, directory-structure

Asking [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/264107/32012) question on mpv player and dvds, I stumbled into a more generic question: is it generally possible to specify a path in which one of the directory names is variable?

Let's say that I want to execute a file with a command. The executable is in `/dir1/dir2/dir3/`, but the name of `dir2` is variable, although it will always contain `dir3` (similar to `VIDEO_TS`, which is always similar to `/media/username/NAME-OF-DVD/VIDEO_TS/` while `NAME-OF-DVD` varies).

If I want to execute that file with a command I have to specify the path. Can a such command be used (with a path in which one directory-name may be "generic")?

Comment: as long as the varying directory level is a **single** directory, what I mean by that, if you have `/dir1/dirX/dir3/dir4` and the `dirX` part is not changing like `dirX/dirY/dirZ` but can only be one of the `dirX`, `dirY` or `dirZ`, then you can reference `/dir1/dirX/dir3/dir4` as `/dir1/*/dir3/dir4`

Comment: @MelBurslan - please post that as answer. In my other case: `mpv /media/username/*/VIDEO_TS` does what I want.

Comment: @MelBurslan - I have edited the question to point out that it is about a single directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash can make use of globbing. Globbing allows you to specify a pattern that will match multiple values. It works similarly to REGEX, but it is important to note they are not the same.

- `*(pattern)` matches a pattern 0 or more times
- `?(pattern)` matches a pattern 0 or 1 times
- `+(pattern)` matches a pattern 1 or more times
- `[ ]` can match a value contained within, including `[a-z]` for a through z
- `( | )` can match values on either side of the pipe

If you don't put a pattern the pattern acts as a wildcard.

So a path like `/dir1/dir2/dir3/` can be represented as:

- `/dir1/*/dir3/`
- `/dir1/dir*/dir3/`
- `/dir1/*(dir2|otherdir)/dir3/`
- `/dir1/dir*[1-99]/dir3/`

For more info check out this link: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

or this one: http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing

Comment: Upvoted, but the [Wooledge Wiki is a *much* better reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)...

Comment: @jasonwryan I concur, that is a better link, added it to the answer

Answer (score 1):

as long as the varying directory level is a single directory, what I mean by that, if you have `/dir1/dirX/dir3/dir4` and the `dirX` part is not changing like `dirX/dirY/dirZ` but can only be one of the `dirX`, `dirY` or `dirZ`, then you can reference `/dir1/dirX/dir3/dir4` as `/dir1/*/dir3/dir4`

In your case `mpv /media/username/*/VIDEO_TS` should work, although, since the DVD titles usually contain spaces, I suggest enclosing the whole path in between double quotes such as `"/media/username/*/VIDEO_TS"`