# remove log files

Tags: linux, rhel, directory-structure

I have a folder which in turn contain multiple sub-folders. All of these sub folders have a log folder. How to clear all the log files alone from all the log folders in these sub-directories using a single command from the parent directory?

Eg,

```
Folder/
  Sub1/
    Log/
      Log1.txt
      Log2.txt
  Sub2/
    Log/
      Log10.txt
      Log11.txt
```

How to clear these log files alone? Please note the  sub folders sub1 and sub2 may contain other folders as well with some other files which should not be deleted.
System is red hat Linux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and use something like `ls` or `tree` to show us your directory structure. Or, at least, use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it clear. I don't understand what is a subdirectory of what. Also, clarify what identified a log file. Is it any `.txt` file? Any file name starting with `Log` and a number?

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash globbing to match multiple folders. Something like:

```
rm ./Folder/*/Log/*
```

Or maybe even better:

```
rm ./Folder/Sub*/Log/*
```

The second one will remove all the files inside the `Log` directory inside a directory that starts with `Sub`. You can add `-r` (recursive) or `-f` (force) to your `rm` command if needed.

For more on bash globbing, you can see another of my answers: [Is it possible to specify a path in which a directory name is variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264110/is-it-possible-to-specify-a-path-in-which-a-directory-name-is-variable/264124#264124)

While that directly answers your question, you may want to consider using `logrotate` to manage old log files: http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html

Comment: Thaks.. Is there any command that will remove all the files except 1 file? For eg, if the log folders contain 1 type of file that is txt1.txt I want them to be untouched..

Comment: @Ra-V this reeeeeeally sounds like you want to use logrotate, but you could still use globbing as per my link `rm ./Folder/Sub*/Log/txt+[2-99].txt` should remove files `txt2.txt` through `txt99.txt` (I didn't test this command though)

Answer (score 2):

Find command is very powerful, in which you are able to perform action on funded object.

```
 find . -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

As you can see, this command find *.txt files and perform rm on it.

To delete files just in Log folders:

```
find . -type d -name "Log" -exec sh -c 'find "$(realpath $1)" -type f -delete' _ {} \;
```

This command find all Log folders then, search for files in them.

Answer (score -1):

For this case it seems like we can use find with type parameter.

```
    find {piyush,jain} -type f
piyush/jain/logs/1.log
piyush/jain/logs/2.log
piyush/jain/logs/3.log
jain/piyush/logs/4.log
jain/piyush/logs/5.log
jain/piyush/logs/6.log

find {piyush,jain} -type f  | xargs rm -f

find {piyush,jain} -type f
```

Comment: you can remove {} part with the directory name you have your log files. and put the same in cron job. if log file has some specific name pattern that can also be added so that it will not delete all files

Comment: If there are more files within the `jain` directory this will also delete those. Also, it may not be desirable to clear out both `piyush/jain/` and `jain/piyush/`. You can also use `find {piyush,jain} -type f -exec rm -f {} \;` to simplify removing them.

Comment: actually i tried to reproduce the issue with two different directories with several sub directories, that's how ended up with this solution.

Comment: But that's distinctly different from what the question is asking. What if that other directory exists but the asker doesn't want to clear out all of its files? It seems like you changed the question so that it could match an answer you already had. If you're going to answer a different question, you should mention that in your answer.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this too in root directory find `maxdepth` for 3 directory `-type f` means you want to find only the files do not include directory and then boom deleted

```
   $ find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -name "*.txt" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: From the question: "Please note the sub folders sub1 and sub2 may contain other folders". Therefore, your solution may remove files that are not log files, for example `Folder/Sub1/otherdir/importantdocument.txt`.