# PCManFM: edit the list of applications available on auto-mount

Tags: linux, settings, removable-storage, multimedia, pcmanfm

The file manager PCManFM has an option (enabled by default) to ask what to do with inserted/mounted volumes (cd, dvds, iso files etc) which is lacking in elementry OS' file manager. That's why I m using [PCManFM for this purpose](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/9488/170).

[image]

When connecting an external HDD:

[image]

When inserting a DVD or mounting an iso-dvd:

[image]

When inserting a CD:

[image]

But can that list be edited somehow in order to add or remove items?

---

**Update** after answer:

`/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` contains this:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/apt=apturl.desktop
xdg-mime default org.pantheon.appcenter.desktop x-scheme-handler/apt
```

No `[Added Associations]` , nor `x-content/audio-cdda`.

Possibly an elementary-os-specific issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for `mimeapps.list`. It can be `$HOME/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` or, if not, look in `$HOME/.config.`

Edit the section `[Added Associations]`.

To add an application in the pop-up list for inserted CD, add this line:

```
x-content/audio-cdda=name_of_application.desktop
```

To add an application in the pop-up list for inserted DVD, add this line:

```
x-content/video-dvd=name_of_application.desktop
```

To remove some of those comment the lines related to them (add `#` in front of the line)

Then do

```
update-mime-database .local/share/mime/
```

or log out and in.

(Mpv player can play dvds but for that you'll have to create a new 'desktop' file in `$HOME/local/share/applications` containing the line `Exec=mpv dvd://` - more details [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265881/32012).)

Comment: Then we try a long shot. Added the Section `[Added Associations]`   Below `x-content/video-dvd=your Programm` and `x-content/audio-cdda=your Programm. `  After `update-mime-database $HOME/.local/share/mime`

Comment: An example for Video-DVD.  I have `x-content/video-dvd=xine.desktop;totem.desktop;brasero-copy-medium.desktop` I can open Video-DVDs, with these Programs. But my Standart_program is `x-content/video-dvd=mpv-dvd.desktop` This desktop file I create by my own.   `xdg-mime query default x-content/video-dvd
mpv-dvd.desktop` I clear with my answer my kontext-menu from clamtk, because it would open my compressed files by default. And it was almost bei all data in the Kontext-menu. I hoped it did help you too.

Comment: I have found the problem with your answer not working for me: the location of `mimeapps.list`  is not the same in all cases; the same may be true for the location of desktop files, and for the path in the command `update-mime-database `. By pure chance I have found on one of my systems the file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` . Adding `x-content/audio-cdda=deadbeef.desktop` in there,  Deadbeef appears in the pop-up list for cd.

Comment: I have made edits to your answer to give the working solution in a general form applyable in all cases. - If accepted I'll make your answer the accepted one too.

Comment: on the location of `mimeapps.list` file: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications#XDG_standard

Comment: My Debian installation is very old since lenny. Maybe  something changed.