# How to get the old pseudo-gui of mpv video player?

Tags: mpv

The default "pseudo-gui" of the MPV video player after version 0.21.

Old look:

[image]

new look:

[image]

The most striking change is the absence of the buttons for a 10 seconds back-forth seek. I suppose they removed those because the mouse wheel is the default way to seek back & forth; only, that function can be changed (in `~/.config/mpv/input.conf`, more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265881/32012)): for example, I use mouse-wheel to change the volume. Also, the old buttons were bigger and therefore easier to use.

Is there a way to go back to the old interface?

---

This question is [posted in order to provide an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17463/210628).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the mpv FAQ ~ [HERE](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/FAQ#I_want_the_old_OSC_back):

Create a `lua-settings/osc.conf` text file inside mpv’s configuration directory (that is: `~/.config/mpv/lua-settings/osc.conf`) with these lines:

```
layout=box
seekbarstyle=slider
deadzonesize=0
minmousemove=3
```

Other options for the on-screen-display - [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/DOCS/man/osc.rst).

---

**UPDATE regarding newer versions:**

~ In relation with this question: [What is the location of the settings-file for the MPV on-screen-controller in newer version (2:0.29.1+git11~bionic)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/544029/341192) and its answer.

In newer versions the location for that file has changed: instead of `~/.config/mpv/lua-settings/osc.conf`, it should be `~/.config/mpv/script-opts/osc.conf`. Some options are deprecated (e.g. `seekbarstyle=slider`; change that to `bar`, `diamond` or `knob`). More details at https://mpv.io/manual/master/#config-syntax.

Comment: by the way, both the question and the answer have been created by me under the same username; only I have at some point deleted that username only to change my mind and re-create it again. Those older posts are signed now by user32012.