# What is the location of the settings-file for the MPV on-screen-controller in newer version (2:0.29.1+git11~bionic)

Tags: gui, settings, mpv

Because some video would not be played in the Mint 19.2 default version of `mpv`, I have fixed that by updating to a newer version from PPA, as said [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/issues/6908#issuecomment-527720714).

In the default version I was able to configure the on screen display so that it showed the older default mpv GUI

[image]

instead of the new default one

[image]

by editing a line in the file `~/.config/mpv/lua-settings/osc.conf`:

```
layout=box
```

As indicated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/404128/341192).

Now that would not work.

At the new version [PPA page](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests) I read that

> Osc config options now go into ~/.mpv/lua-settings/osc.config refer to
>   manpage or pdf in /usr/share/doc/mpv

But that didn't work.

Looking up that pdf, it seems to me it contains the same info as [here](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#on-screen-controller):

> The OSC offers limited configuration through a config file
>   script-opts/osc.conf placed in mpv's user dir and through the
>   --script-opts command-line option. Options provided through the command-line will override those from the config file.

It seems to me that is not specific to the new version; it was referring already to the older versions of mpv that I used; I never followed that setting (is it `/.mpv/script-opts/osc.conf`?) with the default version, but as said above  `~/.config/mpv/lua-settings/osc.conf` (following instructions [here](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/wiki/FAQ#I_want_the_old_OSC_back)). None of those work with my new version though.

So, I have tried without success to make those settings in

- `~/.mpv/lua-settings/osc.config` (as said at new version's PPA page)
- `~/.config/mpv/lua-settings/osc.conf` (which worked with the default version)
- `/.mpv/script-opts/osc.conf` (if I have understood correctly the phrase " script-opts/osc.conf placed in mpv's user dir").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: the correct file is `~/.config/mpv/script-opts/osc.conf`. Some options are deprecated, e.g. `seekbarstyle=slider`.

---

Using the file `~/.config/mpv/lua-settings/osc.conf` (which worked in older version) and running mpv in terminal, I see:

```
[osc] lua-settings/ is deprecated, use directory script-opts/ 
[osc] Invalid setting "slider" for seerekbarstyle
```

So, the needed file is `~/.config/mpv/script-opts/osc.conf`.

As said [here](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#config-syntax),

> seekbarstyle
>
> ```
> Default: bar
>
> Sets the style of the playback position marker and overall shape of the seekbar: bar, diamond or knob.
> ```

The old setting was `slider`. The only available options are now  `bar`, `diamond` or `knob`. (https://mpv.io/manual/master/#config-syntax)

---

The same options work in a command:

```
mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui --script-opts=osc-layout=box,osc-seekbarstyle=bar,osc-deadzonesize=0,osc-minmousemove=3 /path/to/mediafile
```

One could edit the `/usr/share/applications/mpv.desktop` file or create a new one `~/.local/share/applications/mpv.desktop` with the line

```
Exec=mpv --player-operation-mode=pseudo-gui --script-opts=osc-layout=box,osc-seekbarstyle=bar,osc-deadzonesize=0,osc-minmousemove=3-- %U
```

.